# Passing and calling variables and functions between views in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift

I've been wanting to dig into iOS and Mac programming for quite some time and when I heard about swift, I thought this would be a splendid time to do so.

Currently I'm stuck on accessing variables defined in other views.
I'm using a public struct with some static variables that I can access from anywhere, but (apart from my gut instinct telling me I'm doing it wrong) I came to a point where this is simply not a viable solution.
I have a ViewController with an embedded ListView. I have to somehow edit the TopViews Labels when a Cell is deleted in the list.

How can I call the textLabel.text or a reload function from the embedded view?

To create the List I followed [this tutorial](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/developing-ios8-apps-using-swift-create-a-to-do-application/) and built upon it.

Comment: there's no question...

Comment: Sorry, been in front of the screen far too long apparently

Comment: Your question is too vague.  I would have to make a bunch of assumptions about your layout\View design here.  Without knowing much, either use delegation, NSNotification, pass data through segues, a singleton, or a combination of those.

Comment: @MichaelWildermuth I'm only now learning how to deal with Xcode and your comment actually helped a lot. I am looking for ways to pass data and your list of options gave me more than enough to look into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NSNotification.  In the viewDidLoad function in the ViewController you can add an observer like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "doSomethingWhenCellDeleted:", name:"cellDeleted", object: nil)
```

then when the cell is deleted in the embedded view you call:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("cellDeleted", object: nil)
```

then at that time the method doSomethingWhenCellDeleted will be called in the ViewController and that should look something like this:

```
func doSomethingWhenCellDeleted(notification: NSNotification){
//Do whatever
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I needed! Just to clarify, can I use NS NotificationCenter to push/get Data from other views even when not embedded in each other? Also could I somehow send a var value through it?

Comment: Yes, you can.  And you can also send variables.  I'll demonstrate that below, but to be clear, you shouldn't need to use NSNotificationCenter too often.  As @MichaelWildermuth suggested, segues, singletons and delegates are equally useful and each paradigm has a specific application.  If you want to pass information in NSNotification, though, you can do it as follows: var someDictionary = Dictionary<String, String>()
  dataDict["deletedInfo"] = "hello"
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("cellDeleted", object:self, userInfo:dataDict)

Comment: Indeed.  If you're just starting out with a tutorial, it's unlikely you'll need NSNotification